# Document.querySelector() doesn't work with bootstrap css

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

HTML

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="firstapp.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="buttons">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h2>0</h2>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Hello</button>
        <button class="button2">count </button>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Javascript

```
let x = 0

function counter() {
    x++;
    document.querySelector('h2').innerHTML = x;
    if (x % 10 === 0) {
        alert(`counter is now ${x}`);

    }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.querySelector('.button2').onclick = counter; //This statement is for counter function 
    document.querySelector('.btn btn-primary').onclick = function() { //This is Hello Function 
        let heading1 = document.querySelector('h1');

        if (heading1.innerHTML === "Hello!!") {
            heading1.innerHTML = "Goodbye!!";
            //document.querySelector('.btn btn-outline-secondary').innerHTML = 'goodbye';
        } else {
            heading1.innerHTML = "Hello!!";
            //document.querySelector('.btn btn-outline-secondary').innerHTML = 'Hello!!';
        }


    };
})
```

When I Document.queryselector with a local css file it works just fine but as soon as I link a bootstrap class the Java scropt doesn't recognize any bootstrap class and gives out an error " TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
at HTMLDocument. "

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript, elements are selected with **CSS selectors**, not HTML syntax.
Change

```js
document.querySelector('.btn btn-primary')
```

to

```js
document.querySelector('.btn.btn-primary')
```

to denote an element with two class names. Do similarly with the rest by changing spaces to dots.

Answer (score 0):

in primay button add new class for ex 'pbtn' and replace this
document.querySelector('.btn btn-primary')

with this

document.querySelector('.btn.btn-primary')